# Inserting data into the newly created tables from table variable SSIS and not one single table

Tags: sql-server, csv, foreach, ssis

I have been searching for about a week now and I was wondering if anyone may have a clue. I wrote a package to do the following:

1. loop through a parent folder and its subfolders for a csv with a particular naming structure (works)
2. Create a table for each .csv based on the enumeration of each file (works).
3. Import the data into sql server in their own tables with the file name that was created as the table name and not OLE DB Destination (which does not work). It works if it there is destination folder for everything, but when I use table variable that does not work.

What I did was add an Execute SQL task to the for each container to create a table with a variable for the file path that is mapped as an expression in the for each container in a create table query under property sqlstatementsource expression. The tables are created, but when I use the variable that was mapped for the for each loop as the table name or variable in OLE DB Destination I get an error asking for me to check if the table exists. The tables are created, but I cannot get the insertion of the data into their own tables. Even when I bypass the error of "Destination table has not been provided" and run the package. I set delayValidation as true and still nothing. SSIS from what I have seen so far does some cool things. However, I am stuck right now. What else am I doing wrong?

I forgot to mention that the data is going to sql server.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an OLEDB Destination at design time with a variable for a table name.   The OLEDB destination needs to know the table name, and the columns, so that it can pre-map the data flow to the table columns.

You have a couple of other options:

1. You can use BiML to dynamically create your dataflows and destinations.
2. You can use an ExecuteSQL Transformation as your dataflow destination, and write a dynamic SQL statement that inserts each row in the dataflow to the desired table.

Comment: Ok. Is #1 in SSIS, other software, or an add ons? ExecuteSQL transformation as data flow would be a part of SSIS?

Comment: BiML:   http://bimlscript.com/    And yes, the ExecuteSQL transformation is a standard SSIS dataflow component.

Comment: Is ExecuteSQL the same as ExecuteSQL task? When you say in the data flow would this go in the place of where I would put DB destination? If so, I do not see ExecuteSQL Transformation in the list of tasks.